# keeping a message on home page for 24 hours

Tags: php

i have the following php code which i want to run for 24 hours so that one message will remain on homepage for 24 hours? how can i run this script for 24 hours

```
<?php

$SQLstring = "SELECT message as text FROM customers WHERE cust_id='$id'";
            $QueryResult = @mysqli_query($DBConnect, $SQLstring)
            or die("<p>Unable to execute the query.</p>" .
                "<p> Error code " . mysqli_errno($DBConnect) . ":" . mysqli_error($DBConnect))."</p>";

                 $row = @mysqli_fetch_assoc($QueryResult);    
                 echo "<table>";    
                 echo "<tr><td> $row[text]</td></tr>";
                 echo "</table>";

?>
```

Comment: Leave it like this for 24hrs on your server?

Comment: from 00:00 to 23:59 or starting from a specific time?

Comment: Welcome to SO. *I want to* is actually not a real question. Also please think about what you *really* want. Maybe you just want to display a string for 24 hours across requests? How can you say which message to display? You need to add more information so that you'll get fruitful answers. See as well the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) and take some time to search across the site (top-right, there is a search field), you should find something that you need already.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you want to do (or if it's the right approach) but if you want to run something *once* every 24 hours, you can use schedule it a a cron job.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use `set_time_limit(0)` and also you'd have to use `for` loop (or while loop) and `sleep()`

Comment: I think OP question is not actually not ''how to run a script for 24 hours'', but rather ''how to change the message every 24 hours''.

Answer (score 0):

Add a column myDate to your table.
Then you set the value for each row to a certain date.
And with `SELECT message as text FROM customers WHERE cust_id='$id' and DATE(myDate) = DATE(NOW())` the wanted message will be displayed for one day.

Comment: but DATE(NOW()) will return current time , so how can i restrict it to 24 hours?

Comment: the DATE() function allows you NOT to consider hours and minutes. Hence NOW() is stripped of its data and only mantains current date. So that, if you compare with myDate,also stripped to the day only, you get what you need. You're received quite a few useful answers, I think you should +1 some of them, and eventually pick the one which solved your doubt and accept it. Welcome to SO BTW.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't have a script running for 24 hours. Simply what you could do is to always read a value from a table. Then, you simply need to have something changing that value at the intervals of your choice.

If you're on Linux, you can definitely think about CRON (plenty of docs on the Internet - google's first result: http://unixgeeks.org/security/newbie/unix/cron-1.html).

Or, you can have a datetime field. And do something like:

```
SELECT field FROM table WHERE datetime > yesterday
```

or even use an aggregate as MAX - IE max(datetime) to get last inserted value. This approach allows you to keep past values, if you need them for some reason. Compared to solution above (single field involved), you trade some storage for a chance of keeping an archive of data from the past.

At any case, I really  see no point in having a process running for 24 hours just to keep a message there. My 2cc.

Comment: Your query would return rows that should be displayed in the future, too.

Comment: +1'd you. you're right, I thought no future posts could've possibly be published. Of course, this might not be the case. Condition can definitely be improved, but hopefully the idea went through :-)